# Add a non existing Primary Key in a SQL server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, ado.net

I want to insert data in a table that has integers as primary keys. The primary keys will be added by a wide range of random numbers. First I want to check if the primary key exists and then insert it.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Insert()
    {
       bool a=true;

        while (a != false)
        {


            try
            {
                db.test.Add(new test() //insert into test table new data
                {

                    Id = rand.Next(1, 10),
                    name = "test",
                    surname = "test"
                });

                db.SaveChanges();
                a=false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Duplicate");

            }


        }
    }
```

In the first iteration if the number is not duplicate I can successfully insert the new row in database. If in the first iteration it is duplicate entry after `db.SaveChanges();`i jump directly in catch. But the problem arises when in the second iteration the random number is not duplicate it still jumps to catch exception without executing the `a=false` line of code.

Any Idea?

Note: I am not interested on using GUIDs or any other data type.

Comment: Don't insert yourself PK. Use identity instead and let the database generate id.

Comment: @User.Anonymous I am not interested in that solution aswell.

Comment: @MrASD well... what does the exception *say*? Also: does this happen *after* a duplicate has been detected? because if it couldn't insert it the first time, it will still count as a change against `db`, so it will try (and fail) to insert it *every* time from then on

Comment: Ok, I don't understand your concept, but how have you a second iteration if in first iteration all is correct and a is set as false ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes exactly, when it detects a duplicate it keeps trying it even though the next number may not be a duplicate. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @User.Anonymous If the first iteration is not duplicate it successfully inserts the row and the while loop ends. But as mentioned in the above answer, if it detects a duplicate it keeps trying even though there is not aduplicate entry.

Comment: Then add a `finally` block with a=!a inside to break the iteration. But all your algo is wrong, because you don't need a loop.

Comment: And to give a answer in "why ever an Exception", it is because you have a test list so if the 1st item of the list is wrong, it will be ever wrong and you just add another item on list.

Comment: @User.Anonymous Exactly i couldn't use the list again after the exception, by help of Marc Grawell i am always creating a new instance of "database" inside the while loop and the problem is solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I might have an easier solution for you if you don't NEED it to be a random number.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Surname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(255)
); 

INSERT INTO Persons (Name,Surname)
VALUES ('Lars','Monsen');
```

This way you don't even need to do anything with the `PRIMARY KEY`, SQL Server will handle it for you!

Comment: to quote the OP's response to User.Anonymous: "I am not interested in that solution aswell" - I totally agree with you, though; this is the right way of doing primary key generation

Comment: I'm just scratching my head what solution you would want to do this for. Also, I did not see the former comment to OP's post.

Comment: I know what you mean. I feel slightly guilty in that I've apparently solved their problem. To switch to metaphor, it feels like someone was pointing a shotgun at their own foot and couldn't make it fire, and I've just shown them how to release the safety. Sigh.

Comment: and when you go to a distributed system this will only get more and more complex and harder to scale. le sigh.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that once a duplicate key has been generated, it will fail to insert, so it will *keep* trying to insert it each time; to quote OP:

> Yes exactly, when it detects a duplicate it keeps trying it even though the next number may not be a duplicate.

There are 3 main ways of solving this:

1. don't generate your own keys; sorry, but this is the simplest, most obvious, and most supportable mechanism here; `IDENTITY` is your friend
2. if you *fail* to insert something : remove that same something from your ORM context so you don't *keep* failing; there is presumably a `db.test.Remove` method that will suffice; you may also be able to just change the value in the last row, abusing the fact that you know it was the last row that failed: `db.test.Last().Id = newId;` - this is very odd though; everything gets weird if you change identity keys
3. or alternatively, *don't keep re-using the data context after failure*; assuming that `db` is now unusable after the exception, and create a new one for any subsequent operations; IMO this should be done by the same code that originally created the db-context, in a "redo from start" way

Comment: Understanding thank to you that the database itself is unusable helped me understand what is going on. I chose your option 3 and now everything works. Thank you!